# Can I tell from one particle of an entangled pair whether the other particle has been observed?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

I want to ask about a pair of entangled particles, each one heading towards a different group of experimenters.

When one group observes their particle, is it possible for them to tell whether the other group had observed their particle at that point?

Comment: Why the downvotes? This seems a perfectly good question.

Comment: I agree with John Rennie and I have given you an upvote to compensate. There is nothing wrong with the question.

Comment: No, it isn't. The other side will see absolutely no difference in outcome of their measurement depending on whether a pair is entangled, or not. Only if we combine the two measurements after the fact can we tell if the pair was entangled, or not.

Comment: When you raise your hand, is it possible for other people to detect or infer whether or not you've already raised your hand at that point?  Why is this question any different?

Comment: @JohnRennie This kind of "entanglement-and-faster-than-light" question has been asked repeatedly here.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: then vote to close as a duplicate, or if you don't have the required rep add a comment linking the duplicate. I don't recall any exact duplicate of this question, though as you say there are many other related questions already on the site.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch OP says zero things about faster-than-light.

Comment: @DanielSank:  Actually "at that point" seems to imply that the OP has faster-than-light in mind.

Comment: @DanielSank True, but if what the OP asks were possible it would instantly imply FTL-communication.

Comment: @CuriousOne "Only if we combine the two measurements after the fact can we tell if the pair was entangled, or not." -- This is not correct. It would only be correct if we would do a series of measurement on a set of identical qubit pairs.

Comment: @NorberSchuch: OK, I will give you ONE measurement on a photon or on one qubit. How are you going to determine if it was entangled, or not?

Comment: @CuriousOne My point is the opposite. Two measurements on the two qubits of *a single* two-qubit state will now allow you to determine if the state was entangled. You will need to repeat this several times on several coppies of *the same* state.

Comment: Hi DanielSank - You completely nailed the direction I had come from. That's rather impressive! Yes, I was trying to learn the basics of entanglement, and what it looks and feels like, that information cannot be sneaked into an entanglement when one side of the pair is observed finalizes the other side FTL.

Comment: I've been trying to bust the barrier...and it's totally true what you say...that if there was any possibility of one side of a separated entangled pair, could make an observation and out of that, know whether or not the other side had already observed.....that immediately implies superluminal communications.

Comment: I asked the question because it was very easy to construct 'busts' that saw FTL communications. From that I knew I had made a wrong assumption somewhere. And for the same reason that you could infer that's what I had in mind, I was able to infer what the bad assumption was, and frame a question on stack exchange. Cool aye!

Answer (score 2):

No.  The relative probabilities of the observables will be exactly the same as they would have been if the other entangled particle hadn't been observed, it's just that if you later compare the measurements on the two entangled particles, you will find that the measurements are correlated.

Edit (in response to Norbert's comment):  In fact, the measurements will be correlated in a way that would be impossible with classical particles without faster than light signaling.  But the fact remains that nothing you observe about one particle will indicate whether the other particle has been observed.

Comment: You can equally have correlated outcomes with unentangled states.

Answer (score 0):

> When one side of an entangled pair is observed [...]

Whether and in which way a pair had been entangled can of course only be known from both having been observed, and both observations having been (separately) evaluated and the results having been correlated.

> Is it possible for that side to detect or infer whether or not the other side was already observed at that point?

Considering only one side of a pair there cannot be made any inferences about "*the other*"; it cannot even be inferred whether or not some particular "*other side*" might have been "in play" at all.

But it is certainly possible for one side to detect the other side having broadcast their results, before collecting observations pertaining to the own ("*one*") side of the pair. If so, the two events to which the observations belonged were [time-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime#Time-like_interval) related to each other.

Answer (score -2):

No, but if there are only two possibilities they will know what the other measurement will be.